# Connection Issues with DbVisualizer: Trouble Opening Databases

Tags: postgresql, localhost, dbvisualizer

I've successfully opened and run pgAdmin4, and I'm aiming to work on an Entity-Relationship Diagram (ERD) using DbVisualizer because I find its simplicity appealing compared to the ERD generated by pgAdmin4.

However, I'm encountering difficulties as I receive the following error message in DbVisualizer: "localhost:5432 - Ping failed: Cannot connect to 'localhost' on port 5432. Please verify that you have specified a correct host (server) name and port number."

Admittedly, I lack sufficient knowledge to troubleshoot this issue effectively. Despite attempting to seek assistance through chatGPT, the suggested solutions have led me in circles without resolving the problem.

In an attempt to resolve this, chatGPT guided me to open my terminal on my Mac to search for PostgreSQL using various commands. Unfortunately, my computer states that PostgreSQL cannot be found, even though pgAdmin4 is up and operational.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving this connectivity issue.

Comment: I just figured out the problem with the help of chatGPT. For some reason when pgAdmin4 was downloaded it went to localhost port 5433 instead of the default 5432. DbVisualizer, of course, links itself with postgreSQL  but it, too, defaults to port 5432. BUT, why was my computer unable to locate postgreSQL while chatGPT was offering code to put directly to my terminal?